# Ubuntu on Flash USB rather than SSD: performance penalty when not r/w-intense use?

Tags: flash, performance, ssd, xbmc

I plan to turn my fanless HTPC completely silent, exchanging the current HDD for a silent runner. All I expect to do with the machine is to run a media client (XBMC), streaming my media via a network disk. My question is whether there is any noticeable difference in performance, in case if I install a light Ubuntu flavour OS on a flash drive rather than on a SSD.

My thoughts is that since I will not be doing any heavy reading/writing to the disk, once the OS and XBMC is loaded into RAM, I cannot see why differences in read/write speed ([as pointed to here](https://superuser.com/a/65071/390589)) would play a role. [Another SE answer](https://superuser.com/a/483518/390589) notes that the wear on a non-SSD flash drive is a significant issue, even from temporary logs etc. So perhaps I should go for a Ubuntu favour which minimise log writing (temporary writing to RAM etc), whichever that may be.

Are there other issues I have not considered which would give a performance difference here?

Comment: You can adjust the log settings yourself to minimize log writing.    If you're using a USB connected drive, note that the version of USB will make a HUGE difference.  (USB 1.0 would probably be nearly unusable while 3.0 should work well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, there should not be a significant performance problem in the case of an XBMC box. If you think about it, this is almost exactly what the Raspberry Pi does, although technically it uses an SD card rather than a USB drive.

Comment: I have now tested this and it works like a charm: bootup time has gone from 1:10 to around 2 mins, but that is about it, and since the machine is constantly on, the ups are certainly greater than the downs!